# Which list implementation is optimal for removing and inserting from the front and back?

Tags: java, performance, list, data-structures

I am working on an algorithm that will store a small list of objects as a sublist of a larger set of objects.  the objects are inherently ordered, so an ordered list is required.

The most common operations performed will be, in order of frequency:

1. retrieving the nth element from the list (for some arbitrary n)
2. inserting a single to the beginning or end of the list
3. removing the first or last n elements from the list (for some
   arbitrary n)

removing and inserting from the middle will never be done so there is no need to consider the efficiency of that.

My question is what implementation of List is most efficient for this use case in Java (i.e. LinkedList, ArrayList, Vector, etc)?  Please defend your answer by explaining the implementation s of the different data structures so that I can make an informed decision.

Thanks.

**NOTE**

No, this is not a homework question.  No, I do not have an army research assistants who can do the work for me.

Comment: In general though, this is something you could easily just google and look it up yourself. That being said, there's nothing wrong with asking it here, SO is just another part of the freely available internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your first criteria (arbitrary access) you should use an ArrayList. ArrayLists (and arrays in general) provide lookup/retrieval in constant time. In contrast, it takes linear time to look up items in a LinkedList.

For ArrayLists, insertion or deletion at the end is free. It may also be with LinkedLists, but that would be an implementation-specific optimization (it's linear otherwise).

For ArrayLists, insertion or deletion at front requires linear time (with consistent reuse of space, these may become constant depending on implementation). LinkedList operations at front of list are constant.

The last two usage cases somewhat balance each other out, however your most common case definitely suggests array-based storage.

As far as basic implementation details:
ArrayLists are basically just sequential sections of memory. If you know where the beginning is, you can just do a single addition to find the location of any element. Operations at the front are expensive because elements may have to be shifted to make room.

LinkedLists are disjoint in memory and consist of nodes linked to each other (with a reference to the first node). To find the nth node, you have to start at the first node and follow links until you reach the desired node. Operations at the front just require creating a node and updating your start pointer.

Comment: It's worth noting that while insertion or deletion at the front requires linear time, the operation itself is `System.arraycopy`, which will will be jitted to a `memcpy`, which is incredibly fast. So yes, it's linear -- but a fast linear.

Comment: depending on the implementation of the linkedlist (ie. doubly linked lists), operations at the tail end of the list could also be constant as well. Ease of implementation wise however, ArrayLists are the clearest cut.

Comment: @yshavit, may also require additional overhead memory allocation if needs to be resized. Good point though.

Comment: @sshannin True. I brought it up because I'd read somewhere about a benchmark with some reasonably sized data (I forget how big), an ArrayList actually outperformed a LinkedList with operations at the front -- the `arraycopy` outperformed the overhead of object creation and all that jazz. But I don't remember where I read it, so take it with a grain of salt!

Answer (score 3):

I vote for double linked list. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: I assume you meant to link to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
as the interface Deque specifically states "Unlike the List interface, this interface does not provide support for indexed access to elements."

Comment: Well, yes. I was just pointing out the add and remove features.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best data structure for this purpose would be a [deque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque) implemented with a dynamic array, which is basically an `ArrayList` that starts adding elements to the middle of the internal array instead of the beginning. Unfortunately Java's `ArrayDeque` does not support looking up an nth element.

It is, however, pretty easy to implement one yourself (or lookup an existing implementation), and then all three of the described operations can be done in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do all of them with arrayList with minimal confusion if your not worried about efficiency.

i would uses some sort of a queue or stack if i am only inserting at the front or end. They have the least overhead. Or you could also use a linked list.

To remove N elements from the first or end i would use a linked list, you can just delete one node and the ones before or after it are gone. Ie if i delete the first 5 elements just delete the 5th element and the ones before it will disappear. Also if i delete the last 6 elements just delete the 6th to last one and the rest will disappear. And java will do the garbage collecting for you. This would be an order of (1) for this operation.

is this a homework question?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go for LinkedList.  For both inserting a value at the beginning/end of the list and removing the first/last element in the list, it runs in O(1).  This is because all that needs to be changed to carry out these operations is a couple of pointers, a minimally costly operation.

Although ArrayLists retrieve the nth element in O(1) while LinkedLists retrieve the nth element in O(n), ArrayLists run the danger of having to adjust their size when elements are inserted.  What do you suppose happens when the memory allotted for the ArrayList is used up and you try to insert another element?  Well what happens is the ArrayList duplicates itself then allocates more memory (amounting to twice as much as it had initially allocated), a very costly operation.  LinkedLists don't have this problem since, again, all that is done is the addition of a pointer.

I don't know a whole lot about Java Vectors, but if they're anything like C++ vectors, then they're very similar to ArrayLists.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.TreeMap of Long to Object, and use index of i+tm.firstKey()